# PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER VirtualAddress and PointerToRawData fields

Tags: windows, executable, exe, portable-executable

What is the diffence between the VirtualAddress and PointerToRawData fields of IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER structure (declared in WinNt.h) in a Portable Executable?? Why do we have these two diffrent fields and what do they really mean??

Answer (score 6):

`PointerToRawData` tells you where the code/data is inside the file. `VirtualAddress` is where it should be loaded in memory.

Comment: Does that mean that PointerToRaw data is a file offset when the file is on disk??

Comment: Is PointerToRawData always greater than or equal to the VirtualAddrress??

Comment: These two things are very loosely related, you should not assume that one is greater than or equal to the other. Two more articles on PEs: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx).

Comment: Yes I am reading that first article and that's what got me thinking about this PointerToRawData thing.

Comment: If you have read that article and if you have the source code for the PEdump program by Matt Pietrek, you would find that in that project in the Exedump.c file, in the void DumpImportsSection(DWORD base, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTHeader) funcion, Matt has used some relocations of the type thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)( (PBYTE)thunk - delta + base); , where delta = (INT)(header->VirtualAddress - header->PointerToRawData);. I wanted to know the reason for this adjustment.

Comment: I think it's simple. Instead of reading the file from the disk using `fread()` and the like he maps the entire file into memory as-is. Therefore all `PointerToRawData's` become relative memory addresses. So, `base`+`RVA` and `base`+`PointerToRawData` become related, their difference (`delta`) is the difference between where a chunk of the file should've been loaded (for execution by the OS) and where it is actually loaded (by PEdump). He's taking this difference into account.